# SQLalchemy error: ConcurrentModificationError

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I keep having the following error when using SQLalchemy:

```
ConcurrentModificationError: Updated rowcount 0 does not match number of objects updated 1
```

What's the reason behind this error? I get this error while using the `merge` method in sessions objects with postgresql. No other threads are doing access to the db.

Answer (score 0):

Posting the question exactly into Google gives you

"""
Guys,

I am using SA with MySQL. I am trying to update a record by making
a call to session.update(obj). In response I am getting
"ConcurrentModificationError: Updated rowcount 0 does not match
number of objects updated 1"

What are the possible reasons for this error?
"""

the UPDATE statement issued fails to find any rows which match the
expected criterion.  the "concurrent" part comes from the idea that
some other process has already updated the row; however if the UPDATE
statement isnt formed correctly, or if the "rowcount" function on
your DBAPI is busted, that will do it too.

http://markmail.org/message/57nit3c7mw72q5x3

Comment: modify that, "some other process, or other part of code in the same process, even the same thread, has already updated or deleted the row".  For example if you said session.execute("delete from table..."), then the session tries to flush an update on the same row affected by the update, that would do it.  a relationship() that re-uses the mapped table as the "secondary" argument would do it too.   The poster needs to turn on SQL logging and step through what's happening.